# Simple Client-Server program

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to create a simple client-server program using java sockets. Client and server send each other numbers they receive from the keyboard from console. However after client received number from the server and tries to next number server doesn't receive number from client and the programs freeze. I'm a beginner in Java and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicServer
{
    private boolean myTurn ;
    private ServerSocket sock;
    private Socket s;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintStream output;
    private Scanner sc;

    public TicServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        myTurn = false;
        sock = new ServerSocket(9001);
        s = null;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void run() throws IOException
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(this.myTurn == true)
            {
                int pos;
                this.myTurn = false;
                System.out.println("(Server) Insert number: ");
                pos = sc.nextInt();
                output.println(pos);
            }
            else
            {
                int pos;
                this.myTurn = true;
                s = sock.accept();
                input = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
                output = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                pos = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Server received: " + pos);
            }
        }
    }

    private void close() throws IOException
    {
        this.sock.close();
        this.sc.close();
        this.input.close();
        this.output.close();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        TicServer ts = null;
        try
        {
            ts = new TicServer();
            ts.run();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                ts.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the client code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicClient 
{
    private boolean myTurn ;
    private Socket sock;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintStream output;
    private Scanner sc;

    public TicClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        myTurn = true;
        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9001);
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(this.myTurn == true)
            {
                int pos;
                this.myTurn = false;
                System.out.println("(client)Insert number: ");
                sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                pos = sc.nextInt();
                output.println(pos);
            }
            else
            {
                int pos;
                this.myTurn = true;
                pos = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Client received: " + pos);
            }
        }
    }
    private void close() throws IOException
    {
        this.sock.close();
        this.sc.close();
        this.input.close();
        this.output.close();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        TicClient tc = null;
        try
        {
            tc = new TicClient();
            tc.run();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                tc.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running both programs on the same computer using Eclipse.

Comment: PrintStream buffers output. Either create it with a constructor that sets autoflush to true, or explicitly call `flush()` after each print.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I did just that and it gives the same result as before.

Comment: You should only call `Socket.accept()` once, not every time through the loop.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thank you, it worked!